# paplay not working from cron

Tags: command-line, bash, sound, scripts, cron

A little more than a year ago I wrote a notifier app. (on Ubuntu 16.04.7) which played some audio with paplay and then put up a yad window with the text of the notification.  This could be run either from command line or from cron.  Recently I installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 and found that running from command line still works but running from cron doesn't. I have a bin directory below my home directory where the script (remind.sh) is kept. The pared down version of remind.sh is the following.  Note that when I run from cron I get no audio indication the script has run but the trace.txt file gets updated and yad produces a window.

```
#!/bin/bash
# reminder script called from either
#           1. cron or
#           2. directly from shell to pop-up or
#           3. gidday.sh
# produces a 'yad' window with a picture and message in it.

/usr/bin/paplay /home/gary/sounds/marimba.ogg

# trace the run
d=`date`
echo "done -- "$d >> trace.txt

# now put out the window
#
#/usr/bin/yad --borders=50 --scroll --image=/home/gary/Pictures/shrunk-pictures/${ar[$t]} --title="${ar[$t]}" --text-align=center --mouse --width=800 --height=400 --text='<span font="20">'"$txt"'</span>' 2>/dev/null
```

Sorry, I should have provided the following in my original post. The line in crontab that fires off the remind1.sh script is:

```
36 13 30 aug * export DISPLAY=:0 && export MESSG="get movies from lib" && /home/gary/bin/remind1.sh
```

As I said before, this all ran perfectly fine in Ubuntu 16.04. And it still doesn't explain why the paplay command doesn't run but the (uncommented) yad command does.

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided the following in my original post.

Comment: Not sure I'm doing this right but, does anyone have any idea/input as to why paplay doesn't run in Ubuntu 20 but works fine in Ubuntu 16 ??

Answer (score 1):

Jobs run through `cron`, or `systemd` startup scripts aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. `systemd` startup scripts are run as `root`. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings from your `~/.bashrc` are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: Has anyone got any idea why paplay doesn't run in my script on Ubuntu 20.04 but runs fine on Ubuntu 16.04 ??   And to address a comment in the original response, the command part of the crontab line may be interpreted by /bin/sh but the call is being made to a bash script.

Answer (score 0):

You should check output of

```sh
env|grep -i runt
```

For me it was XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
And then put it in environment of crontab job like so:

```sh
* * * * * export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 && paplay sound.wav
```